# what is the difference of partial and addChild?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework3, zend-view

Both are easy to use, both give the same output.
So what is the difference? Are there any advantages to use one or the other? Is there any advantage in performance, security or what ever?

Which one would I use better if I want to manipulate view during runtime?

Comment: first come to my mind is i can use partial in anywhere in view file but i have to add child in controller

Comment: yes, but I would like to have some statements in relation of advantages

Comment: well both of them using view's render method. And render method calls renderChild recursively if there's one. So i don't think so if there's and difference between them.

Comment: ok, that's what I wanted an opinion for. Please post it as answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we talk on zend-view, both using render's view method then calls rendrChild method recursively. So we can say there's not performance difference.

[Here's the zend-view's render method](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-view/blob/master/src/View.php#L168) and [here partial helper using it](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-view/blob/master/src/Helper/Partial.php#L44)